# navigating to viewcontroller inside tabbar issue - ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have one tabviewcontroller and associated tab bars and view controllers as shown in the image.  [image]

My problem is, when i am trying to navigate to some inner view controllers using below code it is not even working, i have tried some other code also, some codes are navigating properly but Tabbar is missing.

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                UITabBarController *tabbar = (UITabBarController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"eventList"];
                self.window.rootViewController = tabbar;
                [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:tabbar animated:YES];
```

i am not that much familiar with `tabviewcontroller`.

Comment: How you're trying to navigate?, the above code just initiated TabBarController and set it as rootViewController to the window. The last line does nothing but pushed the same TabBarController to the NavigationController.

Comment: Looking at your storyboard configuration, it baffles me what you want to achieve. I think you need to do some research on UITabbarcontroller first. I can see many instance of UITabBarcontroller in your storyboard, which I guess are not needed. Only one tabbarcontroller should be enough followed by UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

Change,

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *tabbar = (UITabBarController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"eventList"];
self.window.rootViewController = tabbar;
[self.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:tabbar animated:YES];
```

With,

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
NavigationControllerOfTabbar *navVC = (NavigationControllerOfTabbar *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navVCStoryboardID"];
self.window.rootViewController = navVC;
```

Problem,

- You need to learn know how `UITabBarController` works: Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller).
- You need to learn how iOS app flow/stack works, specifically for `UINavigationController`, `UITabBarController`.
- In your code, this line would be nil: `self.window.rootViewController.navigationController`

Solution,

- Create new class subclassing `UINavigationController`, and give first view controller's name in your storyboard.
- Now initialize this with given code, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Tab bar didn't require navigation controller to operate. 
My suggestion is to remove all code give as above, and make sure that your storyboard is **main interface** in your **target**. Tabs bar should work automatically.

I've noticed that you have other tab bar controllers as children of main tab bar controller. Perhaps they are rudiments of your learning process and had to be removed.

Please make sure that you are setting up proper segues

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2sg7.jpg